# Continuous Density Function and Cumulative Distribution Function Question

Tags: functions

Suppose you choose, at random, a real number $X$ from the interval $[2, 10]$.
Find the density function $f(x)$ and the probability of an event $E$ for this experiment, where $E$ is a subinterval $[a, b]$ of $[2, 10]$.

The answer says it is $f(ω) = 1/8$ on $[2, 10]$.

My thinking was to first make it into the cumulative distribution function and then convert that into the density function because an example in the book just like this one did that. So I did:

Random Variable $X = u$

Distribution Function: $FX(x) = P(u \leq x)$

$u = x$

Then, when you solve that, it's just $x$. Then, to make it into the density formula, you take the derivative. Thus, when you take $\frac{dx}{dx}$, you get $1$.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use [MathJax formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when writing your questions to make them easier to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The cumulative should end up being $0$ at $2$ and $1$ at $10,$ since the whole space is $[2,10].$ So as a cumulative it should be $0$ for $x \le 2,$ then go up in a straight line from $(2,0)$ to $(10,1),$ then be $1$ for $x \ge 10.$ The slope of that line will be $1/8,$ so their answer is right using your method, though you didn't get the right cumulative.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you know that the density is constant on $[2,10]$, and that the area under the curve must equal $1$. So you're solving for some height $h$ such that
$$h(10-2) =1.$$
This gives that the $h = \frac{1}{8}$. So your density is $f(x) = 1/8$, when $2\leq x\leq 10$.

As for the probability of $E$, well that is saying
$$P(a\leq X \leq b) = \frac{\text{Area }E}{\text{Area under curve}} = \frac{h(b-a)}{1} = \frac{b-a}{8}.$$